# How to share the internet between windows and linux

Tags: linux, networking, active-directory, domaincontroller

I have my working pc and a laptop. On the pc I running Windows with domain controller account. When I log on I have access to the Internet. My laptop connected to the same network with Ubuntu operating system. Are there any ways to obtain the Internet access from my laptop? Now i'm simply using remote desktop connection from lap top, but I really need the Internet on my Ubuntu.

IP configuration Windows

```
    HOST NAME  . . .  . .. . . . . . : MN10384632
    DNS  . . . . . . . . . . . .   . : bs.idest.ru
    DNS LOOKUP ORDER. . . . . . . .  : bs.idest.ru
                                      idest.ru
```

LAN - Ethernet:

```
    DNS. . . .  . . . . . . . . . . . :
    DESCRIPTION  . . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet
    Dhcp Enabled.. . . . . . . . . .. .  . . : disabled
    IP-address  .. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.25.6
    Network mask . . . . . . . . . . . .  . : 255.255.255.0
    Gateway . .  ..  . . . . . . . . .  . .. : 10.1.25.1
    DNS. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.10.4
                                               10.1.10.5
    WINS-server . . . . . . . . . . . .  . .: 192.168.100.110


GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         MYMAC
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     CORPORATE
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/83
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.1.25.106/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            10.1.25.1
IP4.DNS[1]:                             10.1.10.4
IP4.DNS[2]:                             10.1.10.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, if you have no rights there is nothing you can do. You need at least to enable routing and NAT on your Windows...

Comment: I will really appreciate if you give me advice how to confugure routing and nat.

Comment: It depends on your Windows version. Most probably you need to right click your Internet connection, then Properties menu item, then Sharing tab. But for older Windows it might be more complicated. Google "how to share internet connection in Windows"

Comment: The computer has the single network adapter. Computer and the laptop in the same network. But in order to use internet i have to authorise with active directory account.

Comment: Show ipconfig /all from the Windows machine and Ubuntu IP/DNS configuration: ip route; ip address; nmcli device show

Comment: added bellow the question

Comment: Can you try to disconnect your Windows host and configure your Linux with 10.1.25.6?

Comment: it doesn't matter. I log on with another account in windows and I can not access the internet. It configured on domain controller that my account has an access to the internet.